# Unable to load KeyStore file in Qpid config

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel, qpid, apache-servicemix

I have a keystore file that works good. I have tested it using the below command ::

```
root@server # java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/apache-servicemix-7.0.0/deploy/qpid.jks SSLPoke esesslx0ghk.se 9443 
Successfully connected
```

Now I am using ServiceMix to deploy a qpid applcation to route queues.

My config is as follows ::

```
  <bean id="amqp" class="org.apache.camel.component.amqp.AMQPComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
       <bean class="org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory">
         <property name="remoteURI" value="amqps://esesslx0ghk.se:9443?transport.keyStoreLocation=/tmp/apache-servicemix-7.0.0/deploy/qpid.jks&amp;transport.keyStorePassword=test123" />
       </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

But when I run my application, I get the ERROR ::

```
2017-05-10 17:30:02,591 | ERROR | mer[CSDP_output] | JmsConnectionFactory             | 226 - qpid-jms-client.jar - 0.0.0 | Failed to create JMS Provider instance for: amqps 
2017-05-10 17:30:02,619 | ERROR | mer[CSDP_output] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | 155 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms - 3.2.17.RELEASE_1 | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'CSDP_output' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Failed to create connection to: amqps://esesslx0ghk.se:9443?transport.keyStoreLocation=%252Ftmp%252Fapache-servicemix-7.0.0%252Fdeploy%252Fqpidd.jks&transport.keyStorePassword=test123; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem 
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create connection to: amqps://esesslx0ghk.se:9443?transport.keyStoreLocation=%252Ftmp%252Fapache-servicemix-7.0.0%252Fdeploy%252Fqpidd.jks&transport.keyStorePassword=test123 


Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem 
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1478)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)[:1.8.0_121] 


Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501)[:1.8.0_121] 
        ... 21 more 
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target 
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)[:1.8.0_121] 
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)[:1.8.0_121]
```

Now on one hand I am 100% sure that the keystore file I have is correct and its path is properly configured. But the application is not able to pick it up. Is there something wrong with this line ?

```
<property name="remoteURI" value="amqps://esesslx0ghk.se:9443?transport.keyStoreLocation=/tmp/apache-servicemix-7.0.0/deploy/qpidd.jks&amp;transport.keyStorePassword=test123" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handing the client a key store but in general you should be handing it a trust store as that is what tells the client which server certificates it trusts.  You only give a key store when you are doing mutual authentication and the client needs to provide a certificate to the remote.

My first suggestion would be to set the transport.trustStoreLocation as defined in the client [documentation](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.22.0/docs/index.html).

If that doesn't work then it's time to break down and do some debugging of the [SSL handshake](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html).

Comment: Thanks. Changing it to `transport.trustStoreLocation` worked.